# I need help to build ERC-721 contract with solidity version 5.0 or higher

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to write a contract with ERC-721 token system. I have experience with ERC-20, so I thought I can find a tutorial and follow the tutorial. However, tutorials I found are based on solidity version between 4.0~4.2. Nowadays we use 5.0~6.0. Therefore tutorial codes are not working. Is there any tutorial, or code can I look and learn? HELP!

I tried to fix the code, and make suitable for 5.0 or higher, but I failed. 
Therefore I tried to downgrade solidity and use docker but still get

> Error: CompileError: ParsedContract.sol:3:1: ParserError: Source
>   "zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol" not found:
>   Unknown exception in read callback. import
>   'zeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Token.sol'; this
>   error. :(

+
I found https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity , this but I do not know how to write test. Thank you for your time to read this !.

Answer (score 1):

due to renaming, `ERC721Token.sol` is no longer available in the latest version of OpenZeppelin v2.3.0. change `ERC721Token.sol` to `ERC721.sol`, and it should work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however still same error :((. and ERC721.sol is already exist.

Comment: @Chol, can you post your import statements of your `ParsedContract.sol`?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you have a look at the OpenZeppelin documentation:
https://docs.openzeppelin.org/v2.3.0/tokens#erc721

If you have more questions about OpenZeppelin you can always ask in the [community forum](https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/)

I can put together a sample contract in the community forum if you need.